# How to automatically build Class Library project in the same solution, when I 'F5' the Start Project

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, build, uwp, visual-studio-debugging

In visual studio I created a solution with class library project and UWP project. But when I hit the F5 Key to build the UWP app which references the class library, the class library does not build. I have to manually build the library in order to see the changes. How to automatically build the class library when I press the F5

Comment: I think that you can use 'Rebuild all' button in this case. See [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2376810/force-visual-studio-to-always-rebuild-all-when-debugging#2376810]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by going to solution properties (right click on solution in Solution Explorer > Properties) and there in `Project Dependencies` tab you have to select your app in combobox and check that it depends on your class library.

Comment: @Aslam please mark as answered. May help other people with the same problem :)