# C# compiling for 32/64 bit, or for 'Any CPU'?

Tags: .net, assemblies, 64-bit, 32bit-64bit, anycpu

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
> [What does the Visual Studio "Any CPU" target mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target)

I've noticed that when compiling C# code in Visual Studio, there are typically options for compiling for 32/64 bit systems, and there's also one for compiling for *[Any CPU](http://web.archive.org/web/20151215192101/http://visualstudiohacks.com/articles/visual-studio-net-platform-target-explained/)*.

What's the difference between the two options? Does choosing *Any CPU* only compile down to an intermediate byte code while the first option compiles down to machine code (this sounds unlikely to me)? Or something else?

Comment: Also see: [Visual Studio “Any CPU” target](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/visual-studio-any-cpu-target)

Answer (score 195, accepted):

### On a **32-bit** machine:

- **Any CPU**: runs as a 32-bit process, can load **Any CPU** and **x86** assemblies, will get `BadImageFormatException` if it tries to load an **x64** assembly.
- **x86**: same as **Any CPU**.
- **x64**: `BadImageFormatException` always.

### On a **64-bit** machine:

- **Any CPU**: runs as a 64-bit process, can load **Any CPU** and **x64** assemblies, will get `BadImageFormatException` if it tries to load an **x86** assembly.
- **x86**: runs as a 32-bit process, can load **Any CPU** and **x86** assemblies, will get `BadImageFormatException` if it tries to load an **x64** assembly.
- **x64**: same as **Any CPU**.

It is the **JIT compiler** that generates an assembly code that's compatible with the requested target based on this flag.

Comment: That's a great answer covering all permutations. Just to add that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2418287/848344) will determine if a DLL/assembly is 32 bit, 64 bit, or "Any CPU".

Comment: Looks like this has changed in .NET 4.5. Here's a link to the updated answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12066861/1993242

Comment: I was wondering why my AnyCPU wasn't running as 64-bit on my PC. Turns out we now have the prefer 32-bit flag. See the answer above fore more info.

Answer (score 20):

*x86* - Your software will always run in 32-bit mode, both on 32-bit systems and 64-bit systems.

*x64* - Your software will always run in 64-bit mode, will run on 64-bit system but won't run on 32-bit system.

*Any CPU* - Your software will run according to your OS. If you have a 32-bit OS you code will run in 32-bit mode. If you have a 64-bit OS your code will run in 64-bit mode.

Comment: As a side note to this answer, it's just a flag in the binary, what option you choose doesn't change its contents. It can actually be modified later by using CorFlags tool.