# My Application not allow Interop.CDO to download a file

Tags: c#, security

My Application does not allow Interop.CDO to download a file from FTP server, what can I need to do to resolve this issue?

> Error message :
>
> Could not load file or assembly
>   'Interop.CDO, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
>   or one of its dependencies. Была
>   сделана попытка загрузить программу,
>   имеющую неверный формат.

Here's the English equivalent of the error:

> An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking.

Comment: Just a few people can read Russian. I can, but I don't understand what is your questions. Please put more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you check it's not a 32/64 bit issue? The underlying COM CDO dll is probably only supporting 32-bit processes. Your program maybe compiled as "x64" or as "Any CPU", but running on a 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Compile your program with X86. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229768/c-compiling-for-32-64-bit-or-for-any-cpu

Comment: the problem that my application should run in 64 bit mode

Comment: there are any other solution to send mail either CDO ?

Comment: To download a file using FTP? or to send email?

Comment: @Msemlmi - I asked because in the question you say to send a file using FTP. Anyway, you can send email using http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx, otherwise, if you want CDO-like stuff, Outlook Redemption supports 32 and 64 bit processes: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/