# C# windows app win 7 64 bit not running in win 7 32 bit

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I have developed small C# window app in win 7 64 bit machine and created a setup package using target framework 32 bit. but when i run that installer in another win 7 32 bit machine. It gets installed but when i run the exe file created by setup nothing happens. I am not able to find whats happening. Any help will be appreciated. thx...

Comment: This might be of help:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229768/c-sharp-compiling-for-32-64-bit-or-for-any-cpu

Comment: Get to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229768/c-sharp-compiling-for-32-64-bit-or-for-any-cpu?lq=1

Comment: You have not specified what framework is the application implemented in. Do you have the same .NET frameworks installed? You should also look what error messages you find in eventlog after you run the application. It might be something helpful there.

Answer (score 1):

Try at the Project Solution's properties set the  configuration for Any CPU or x86