# Conversion to x64 platform in visual studio failing

Tags: visual-studio-2012, 64-bit, badimageformatexception

So I built a huge website for my company using the AnyCpu option.  I didn't think it would matter - I have a 64bit machine with x64 windows, it's getting deployed to a x64 server, and there's no attached dll's, so it should just all be in 64, right?

Well, in the process of trying to implement some security, the company's support told us the application MUST be strictly x64.  I figured it was, but to humor them, I went into the configuration manager, and changed all the target cpu, platform etc settings to x64.

Unfortunately now, it breaks when I hit f5 to run it.  I've run into this before, I think, and I vaguely remember needing to delete some temp internet files somewhere, but I tried closing VS, deleting the bin folder, deleting the root folder from /framework/tempASPfiles... but I still get the BadImageFormatException - "an attempt was made to load the program with an incorrect format."

What's the best and fastest way to convert an app to x64? and am I right in thinking I need to delete some files somewhere?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5229768/c-sharp-compiling-for-32-64-bit-or-for-any-cpu

Comment: I understand *what* it does, just trying to find out if having ran it as anycpu since the beginning requires me to undo anything else, or why I'd be getting an error by changing it if it doesn't change anything...