# Visual Studio 2010 not rebuilding/recompiling

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build, compilation, rebuild

I was working on a project when all of a sudden VS stopped recompiling my project each time I debugged (mid way through working... I never changed anything). So it keeps running the same old build over and over.

I don't want to have to "clean build" each time, and I've followed the instructions here ([Visual Studio 2010 doesn't rebuild changed code unless I manually select "Rebuild"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489794/visual-studio-2010-doesnt-rebuild-changed-code-unless-i-manually-select-rebuil)). Surprisingly, they were already set (prompt to build when project outdated, build is checked under configuration manager).

However, it still never prompts me (except for after clean), and it's getting really frustrating. I'm using VS c++ if it helps.

Comment: I've tried all the basics (such as googling, I linked one of the similar questions)...

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. This might solve your problem:

Tools->Options->Project and Solution->Build and Run.

There is an option what to do for "On run, when projects are out of date". Set this to "always create". This will mean that if you compile a project which depends on another project in your project folder, then the other project is compiled first, just as you want.

In my case, this option was set but then set to something else after a crash of VS2010.