# Visual Studio 2015 not building solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Today I've noticed that building solution on VS2015 has stopped working. it just shows

```
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Even though I edit it (meaningful changes) to test it and then hit compile solution. It only works if I force a build of the current file or a full solution rebuild.

Is there a solution to this? I can't rely on single file build as I may have edited other files so I'm stuck to full rebuild for the time being which is annoying.

I'm using C++ by the way, I'm not sure if this makes a difference with the recent changes to VS2015 to not include C++ by default.

[Edit1]
I've tried this: [Visual Studio 2010 doesn't rebuild changed code unless I manually select "Rebuild"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489794/visual-studio-2010-doesnt-rebuild-changed-code-unless-i-manually-select-rebuil)

And the file is part of the solution. I double click it to make sure it opens the file. Then edit it and then click build. It's true that I've used external programs to edit it but even when I do it on VS it doesn't seem to work. I've also checked toggling the options to prompt me if the file is being changed outside the environment but nothing seems to change.

[Edit2]
I've gone through all the options in Tools >> Options >> Project and Solution >> Build and Run nothing seems to work. Also in the Configuration Manager the only project is ticked to build.

Comment: From the error, it is not recognizing the file you are trying to compile as being updated. (hence, 1 up to date)

Comment: make sure the `cpp` file is part of the project, not just opened as a stand alone file.

Comment: Maybe go to Configuration Manager and check builds?

Comment: Have you looked into :

    Tools > Options > Projects & Solutions > Build and Run ?

Problem could come from a setting being modified there. (Sounds dumb af... but my IT senses are tingling)

Comment: Check the dates of the files in the project. If they are in the future then it does not know it needs to do the build.

Comment: Hey Robert, I'm getting the same issue with vs2015 on Wins10 Pro and building any C++ type of projects - "failed" but no errors are outputted. I think it's related to the "Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015" since it seems to be installed but doesn't show up in "Programs and Features."  I'm pretty sure none of the above and below suggestions worked for you. Did you figure it how to resolve the issue? If so, Please, please post.

Comment: @JohnW_ARToolKit I just reverted to VS2013.

Comment: "@Robert Rodriguez", It turns out that having Visual Studio 2017 and 2015 installed side-by-side, the Visual Studio gang really, really wants you to start using Visual Studio 2017 (MSBuild.exe, 2017 version) to build. Somehow the vs2015 MSBuild executable got stomped to be a zero byte length file... It was stomped on the day I installed vs2017 community... So I wasted 2 days looking at that one. Blah.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the following:

Right click on File -> Properties
There should be an Option like "exclude from build" or "Do Not build".
Check that "no" is selected.