# VS 2015 doesn't rebuild startup project when referenced project changed

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

In VS 2015
I have UWP C# project, which references UWP Windows Runtime Component C++ project, which references native shared C++ library.

`UWP C# -> UWP WRT C++ -> unmanaged C++`

Basically WRT project is just connect C# with C++. it doesn't contain any files, all calls go thorugh PInvoke's.

Every time I make changes in native C++ library and press run, I see in Outout windows that it rebuild that C++ project. But it somehow doesn't affect startup project. (may be it just don't copy C++'s dll?)

To see the changes, I have to clean/rebuild startup project each time.

P.S. I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3544451/1559666 - but it didn't help me.