# Visual Studio 2017 doesn't rebuild changed code upon run

Tags: visual-studio, build, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 ver 15.5.0 (the latest) to develop some CUDA/C++ code. The issue is that upon code changing I have to manually select rebuild solution. When I press f5 button it does not build a new version. When I press build, it says that solution is up-to-date (although code has been changed).

I noticed that this thing occurs in other projects too, so it should be related to global VS settings. 
I am familiar with  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489794/visual-studio-2010-doesnt-rebuild-changed-code-unless-i-manually-select-rebuil) topic and I made sure that the option "always build" is selected.

Thanks,
Mikhail

Comment: Does anyone have the same problem?

Comment: Yes, in my instance visual studio consistently fails to properly rebuild code that has changed, resulting in linker errors or runtime exceptions. If I don a clean/rebuild it works fine.

Comment: It has been reported, and seems to have been fixed, but I guess it's regression... Anyone with this problem should first check the setting at `tools-> options -> Projexts and Solutions -> Build and Run -> On Run, when projects are out of date`. If it is not set to **Never Build** then click on the feedback icon in the top-right (between the notifications flag icon and the quickluanch combobox). Search for "recompile changes" and vote. Edit: fixed but not yet in the currently released version, for now it's in the [15.6 preview 4](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/preview/) version.

Comment: I have a similar issue, but with .asm assembly files in a project. I am using VS 2022.