# Web Forms - Recompilation if change ascx file in VS, in notepad - no

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, recompile

There is asp.net web forms application, it is on my local iis and opened in VS2017. When I develop and testing it, I often do small changes to aspx, ascx, and aspx.cs files and it not causes recompile.I see my changes so I do not need relogin. I see my changes immediatelly.

But I notice it start to recompile too often, for example when I change ascx file in VS (and even not save it!) - I see loosing session(relogin) - so it is recompiling. And it is strange because if I do my changes to same file with help of notepad instead VS - there is no recompilation. I suspect it is some bug of VS, maybe it changes other files in folder and it causes recompilation? How to know real cause of recompilation?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3544451/6911980) might be what you're referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo! Found the answer after 20 hours of investigation. Just remove optimizeCompilations option from web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" optimizeCompilations="true"...  >
```

this flag causes app domain recycle on small changes in aspx files in our project.

Enjoy!