# Why my visualstudio don't automatically build the start project when I debug the project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Now when I Start Debug my project ,VS didn't automatically build.I must build the solution  manually.I google the question,but there is nothing to help me.

Is there someone know the reason,How to solve the problem?

Edit:
The Question is duplicated of [Why doesn't F5 rebuild project before execution in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922330/why-doesnt-f5-rebuild-project-before-execution-in-visual-studio)

Comment: Go to properties and check the Build / compile properties

Comment: @Nadeem_MK Could you give me more detail about that(compile properties)?thanks

Comment: http://bit.ly/1z1gW8O

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't F5 rebuild project before execution in Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922330/why-doesnt-f5-rebuild-project-before-execution-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

Open Tools -> Options ->Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run.
Set option "On run, when projects are out of date"  to Always build.