# Starting Debugger doesn't rebuilt project in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2008

After I make a change in one of my projects, the project is not built automatically after I click "F5" or click the button to run the Debug. Every time a change is made I have to first click Build->Build Solution and then run the debugger.

I have already tried all of the solutions suggested here:  [Why doesn't F5 rebuild project before execution in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922330/why-doesnt-f5-rebuild-project-before-execution-in-visual-studio)
All of the projects have the "Build" checkbox checked in Solution Propertys->Configuration Properties->Configuration, and the Build and Run setting in Options-> Projects and Solutions is set to "Always Build".

This project used to build automatically, but some time ago it has stopped.

Comment: Visual Studio takes a shortcut.  If it thinks that building is not necessary then it won't even attempt to run MSBuild.  Like Build > Build does.  That's nice and quick, everybody likes that.  Until it guesses wrong, you have absolutely nothing to look at to figure out why.  Major bummer.  All you can reasonably do is go back into source control to look for a change that caused it to go stoopid.

Comment: Don't know if it will help, but there may be something in the .suo or .user files that is causing the issue. Try deleting those files (after closing Visual Studio.)

Answer (score -1):

Below link may solve your problem regarding debugging....

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx

Regards,
Sagar Rupani

Comment: It doesn't...
I can not find anything in that article that addresses this problem.