# Can't debug in Visual Studio 2017 (This project is out of date)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

I'm starting to learn C++ so I installed Visual Studio 2017. 
Once I was in the program I created a console application and made a simple hello world program following along with the book I was reading.
I can't seem to debug the program without a pop-up box saying, "This project is out of date" (screenshot included).

The program does run as long as I click yes, but I'm wondering why it's doing this, it didn't do this when I was using C#. Is there something corrupt with Visual Studio?

Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: Well you changed something in the code, and didn't build the solution, that's what it is telling you.

Comment: If you make changes in your source, and don't rebuild the program before attempting to run it, you will get something like this. It's nothing wrong, just say "Yes" so the program is rebuilt.

Comment: Your c# solutions are most likely configured to "always build before run" or something like that.

Comment: Oh okay, thanks guys. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4922449/366904