# How to force Visual Studio to always rebuild another C# project when running a test project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, compilation

I have a project that does some IL injection into an assembly. To test this code I have two projects:

1. A project that generates an assembly to be injected into.
2. An MS test project that does the injection and then verifies that injection has occurred.

The problem is that project 1 needs to be rebuilt each time the tests are run so that the assembly is clean.

I've tried

- [How do I force a rebuild when the project configuration changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334774/how-do-i-force-a-rebuild-when-the-project-configuration-changes).
- Cleaning the project in a pre-build event.

But neither of these approaches work. The only thing that does work that I've found is overwriting a dummy text file in project 1, but this is not acceptable as the IDE opens a message box asking to reload it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are two suggestions to try:

1. Try cleaning project 1 as a post-build event of the test project.  That assumes that you won't need to examine the assembly when the test fails.
2. Add a pre-build event to your test project that calls devenv with /rebuild on project 1.

Comment: Thanks, I'd already tried both of those and neither work. The first just deletes the assembly. The second causes visual studio to hang (I suppose there is some kind of circular dependency)