# VS2010 requiring me to "Clean Solution" before every debug in order to break point new code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, build

I am writing a .Net 4 Windows Forms app.

For some reason with this latest project, it is forcing me to clean the solution in order for the debugger to "see" new code.  It has not done this before and it is irritating.

Does anyone know how to make it so "Start Debugging" forces a clean and rebuild before it starts or how to fix this in VS2010?

Comment: Does it rebuild the project at all when you start debugging?

Comment: Probably this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922330/why-doesnt-f5-rebuild-project-before-execution-in-visual-studio

Comment: Also see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334774/how-do-i-force-a-rebuild-when-the-project-configuration-changes

Comment: Also see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334774/how-do-i-force-a-rebuild-when-the-project-configuration-changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the "Configuration Manager" and check if the "Build" checkbox is checked for every project.

Answer (score 1):

> Also :
>
> Right Click on the solution in the solution explorer.
>
> Click on "Properties".
>
> Navigate to configuration Properties -> Configuration on the left side of the window.
>
> Make sur the "Build" checkbox is checked on the line of your project.

From Mrchief's link fixed it.